# How do I drop a primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a primary key name idnumber. how can I remove its primary key in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you, but are you sure you want to drop the primary key?

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 1):

Help on alter table syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Why would you want to drop the the primary key? If you created it by mistake then you can change it by

```
alter table T drop primary key, add primary key (C);
```

Where T is the table name and C is the column containing the correct primary key

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to drop and create a new primary key if you currently have it on AUTOINCREMENT, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(your_column);
```